How to create formating tag based on user select from multiselect dropdown in javascript
I have formating (bold,italic,underline) list in multiselect dropdown. Based on user selection i need to create formating tag.
example: if user select bold and italic from dropdown i need to create tag like <b><i></i></b> and if user select only italic i need to create tag like <i></i>
I have tried below:
<select id="multiple-select" multiple>
    <option value="Bold">Bold</option>
    <option value="Italics">Italics</option>
    <option value="Underline">Underline</option>    
</select>
<button id="Apply">Apply</button>

javascript code:
   $("#Apply").click(function(){
      var selectedtag = $("#multiple-select option:selected").val();
      var selectedtag = $("#multiple-select option:selected").val();
      for(var fr=0;fr<selectedtag.length;fr++)
      { 
        var createtag = '<'+selectedtag[fr]+'></'+selectedtag[fr]+'>';
        var createnode = document.createElement(createtag); 
      }
   });

Expecting: based on input need to create tags

What do you mean by creating a tag? Generate the <b><i></i></b> string content? Create the corresponding HTML elements? If so, where? And what's currently preventing you from doing that? Where's the JavaScript that you're supposedly struggling with? Or is this just a matter of "someone write this for me"?

Directly assign tags as the values of corresponding options.
Use 2 variables to contact opening and closing of tags
Finally, combine them to get the final tag html.
Working snippet:


$("#Apply").click(function() {
  let selectedtag = $("#multiple-select").val();
  let openTags = '';
  let closeTags = '';
  for (fr = 0; fr < selectedtag.length; fr++) {
    openTags = openTags+'<' + selectedtag[fr] + '>';
    closeTags = '</' + selectedtag[fr] + '>' + closeTags;
  }
  console.log(openTags + closeTags);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiple-select" multiple>
  <option value="b">Bold</option>
  <option value="i">Italics</option>
  <option value="u">Underline</option>
</select>
<button id="Apply">Apply</button>




Jerry,  "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

You will need to iterate over all selected options and construct the tags accordingly.


document.getElementById("Apply").onclick = function() {
  var selectedOptions = document.getElementById("multiple-select").selectedOptions;
  var tags = { 'Bold': 'b', 'Italics': 'i', 'Underline': 'u' };
  var openTags = '';
  var closeTags = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[selectedOptions[i].value];
    openTags += '<' + tag + '>';
    closeTags = '</' + tag + '>' + closeTags;
  }

  var finalTag = openTags + closeTags;
  console.log(finalTag);
};
<select id="multiple-select" multiple>
    <option value="Bold">Bold</option>
    <option value="Italics">Italics</option>
    <option value="Underline">Underline</option>    
</select>
<button id="Apply">Apply</button>




I have replaced jQuery with vanilla JavaScript.
I have created an object tag to map the text options to their corresponding HTML tags.
The openTags and closeTags strings are used to build the opening and closing tags in the correct order.
The for loop iterates over the selected options and constructs the tags.
finalTag contains the concatenated result of the selected formatting tags.

